# Monitorix using nginx

Tags: nginx, monitoring

I have a VPS serving a website using nginx and jetty and everything works fine. The website is accesible through my .com domain.

I have installed monitorix and I want to access monitorix web user interface which should be served as well by nginx (I don't want to install another server like lighttpd or apache just for monitorix). In the monitorix documentation it says that it should be accessible through http://localhost/monitorix. I have tried www.mydomain.com/monitorix but it shows my custom 404 page, and I have also tried to access http://localhost/monitorix with both curl and lynx and I get the 404 page as well.

How can I configure nginx to serve monitorix WUI? It is ok if I configure it to serve it only to localhost and I can create an SSH tunnel from my computer to see the page and graphic statics.

Thank you!!

Comment: do you have a `location` and an `alias` in your nginx configuration for monitorix? what does the nginx access.log and error.log say when you try to access it?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx don't support CGI. You can try [SimpleCGI](http://wiki.nginx.org/SimpleCGI), but i recommend install Apache for Monitorix.

Comment: I am already using [fast-cgi](http://wiki.nginx.org/FcgiExample) with nginx and it works flawlessly, so that's not a problem...

Comment: Nginx support FastCGI, but not support CGI. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Comment: @alvosu It is not a problem. Every CGI script can be run using FastCGI process manager. Apache for this job is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fcgiwrap to access the Monitorix cgi script from NGINX.

```
    location /monitorix {
        alias /var/lib/monitorix/www/;
    }

    location /monitorix-cgi/ {
        alias /var/lib/monitorix/www/cgi/;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
```

As documented in the [FAQ](https://www.monitorix.org/faq.html#Q120) the web server needs write permissions in the imgs directory:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/monitorix/www/imgs
```